The Downloads folder is not updated
The problem appears on Windows 10 in Chrome and Firefox browsers. Reproduction steps:

Open the Downloads folder in Explorer.
Download any file in the browser.
Open the list of downloads in the browser and click the Show in folder button for the latest download.

What happens: the previously open Explorer window with the Downloads folder moves to the top. But the downloaded file is not there - the folder window has not been updated. If you force it to update, the file will appear.
What is expected: if the file has been downloaded, it should appear in the window with the Downloads folder.
I want to understand is this problem only specific for my computer? And how can I fix it?
If this happens to everyone, is there any way to get around this problem?
I'm writing an extension for the Chrome browser that downloads a file and I want the user of my extension to see the downloaded file when they click on the Show in folder button.

For what it's worth, downloads show up immediately for me when I have the Downloads folder open. I also have different downloads folders configurd for all browsers.

Every time I have had a failure to refresh, it has been because of a shell extension.  That downloads window asked windows to be told when that folder changes and something got in the way.  Probably an extension.  It could be a column handler or any other aspect of a shell extension.  You should never need to F5 refresh in a folder.

I would suggest trying this tool to disable every extension you can and toggle everything in startup to be sure.  Then add them back one at a time.  You can usually leave the MS ones alone.

First thing to do is figure out if it is an issue with Windows or with Chrome.
Right click a test file, Save as..., and choose a location other than Downloads.
If it appears immediately, then the issue is likely with Explorer and you could try resetting your folder display options to defaults or deleting temp files such as "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent".
If the problem persists, then try again with your antivirus disabled.
